# Font size text citations and footnotes

Tags: fonts, size

how can I set out text citations 11pt and footnotes 10pt with "arsclassica"?

Thanks for your help

Comment: For those who don't know what "arsclassica" is: Is it a document class, a LaTeX package, something else entirely? If it's not a document class, which class do you use? Regarding the formatting of citation call-outs: do you use a citation management package such as `natbib`? Please advise.

Comment: Is there any news here?